# "RuntimeError: dictionary keys changed during iteration" when attempting to call add_attachment for Jira issue object, but dictionaries aren't used?

Tags: python-3.x, jira, python-jira

I am attempting to just add a csv file to my issues as a test, but I keep receiving the error:

```
RuntimeError: dictionary keys changed during iteration
```

Here is the code (I've removed the parameters for server, username and password):

```
from jira import JIRA

options = {"server": "serverlinkgoeshere"}
jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=('username', 'password'))
issuesList = jira.search_issues(jql_str='', startAt=0, maxResults=100)
for issue in issuesList:
    with open("./csv/Adobe.csv",'rb') as f:
        jira.add_attachment(issue=issue, attachment=f)
    f.close()
```

I'm at a loss, I'm not changing any dictionary keys in my code. Here is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/extractor/main/jiraCSVDupdate.py", line 8, in <module>
    jira.add_attachment(issue=issue, attachment=f)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jira\client.py", line 126, in wrapper
    result = func(*arg_list, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jira\client.py", line 787, in add_attachment
    url, data=m, headers=CaseInsensitiveDict({'content-type': m.content_type, 'X-Atlassian-Token': 'nocheck'}), retry_data=file_stream)
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jira\utils\__init__.py", line 41, in __init__
    for key, value in super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).items():
RuntimeError: dictionary keys changed during iteration
```

References:
Jira add_attachment example:
https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples.html#attachments

add_attachment source code:
https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/_modules/jira/client.html#JIRA.add_attachment

Answer (score 3):

The root of the problem is found at `jira.utils.__init__py`:

```py
for key, value in super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).items():
    if key != key.lower():
        self[key.lower()] = value
        self.pop(key, None)
```

This is a programming mistake: one should not modify the data structure that is being iterated over. Therefore, this requires a patch and must be the only accepted solution for this.

In the meantime, I suggest a monkey patch:

```py
import jira.client

class CaseInsensitiveDict(dict):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(CaseInsensitiveDict, self).__init__(*args, **kw)

        for key, value in self.copy().items():
            if key != key.lower():
                self[key.lower()] = value
                self.pop(key, None)

jira.client.CaseInsensitiveDict = CaseInsensitiveDict
```

The trick here is that you iterate over a copy of your dict structure, by doing `self.copy().items()`, and not your original one - the `self` one.

For reference, my package version: `jira==2.0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Should be fixed from jira lib version 3.1.1  (https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/commit/a83cc8f447fa4f9b6ce55beca8b4aee4a669c098)

so assuming you use reqirements edit your requirements.txt file with
`jira>=3.1.1` and install them `pip install -r requirements.txt`

otherwise use:
`pip install jira==3.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

This works as a fix using Python 3.9.

The dictionary keys in the following lines in `client.py` in the Jira site-packages are not all lower case.

`headers=CaseInsensitiveDict({'content-type': None, 'X-Atlassian-Token': 'nocheck'}))`

`url, data=m, headers=CaseInsensitiveDict({'content-type': m.content_type, 'X-Atlassian-Token': 'nocheck'}), retry_data=file_stream)`

This works as a solution.

You can alter the dictionary keys to be all lower case. This will then allow the attachment to be added to the JIRA ticket.

`headers = CaseInsensitiveDict({'content-type': None, 'x-atlassian-token': 'nocheck'}))`

`url, data = m, headers = CaseInsensitiveDict({'content-type': m.content_type, 'x-atlassian-token': 'nocheck'}), retry_data = file_stream)`